# Kubernetes. Why is a pending pod deleted after 20 secs

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

If I deploy a pod with nodeName set to an name that does not (yet) exist in the cluster the pod is first in the pending status but then is removed afted 20 seconds.
This behaviour is different when I specify node name using podAffinity and the pod get scheduled as soon as the node name is found.

There is the yaml file :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: firstpod
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: Name
            operator: In
            values:
            - unknownnode
  containers:
  - name: container
    image: ubuntu
    command: [sleep]
    args: ["600"]
#  nodeName: unknownnode
```

Why is the pod delete in the first case and is there a way to customize this behavoiur?

Answer (score 4):

It is as per design or limitation of `nodeName`. Please see the documentation about [nodeName](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#nodename). From the documentation:

> Some of the limitations of using nodeName to select nodes are:
>
> - If the named node does not exist, the pod will not be run, and in some cases may be automatically deleted.
> - If the named node does not have the resources to accommodate the pod, the pod will fail and its reason will indicate why, for example OutOfmemory or OutOfcpu.
> - Node names in cloud environments are not always predictable or stable.